# SPRING CLOUD: RestTemplate postForObject cannot send request body

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

This is my consumer request function:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/spuSkuInfo")
    public DataResponseDto<Map<String, Object>> addSpuAndSkuInfo(@Valid SpuSkuInfoBo spuSkuInfoBo) {
        String url = REST_URL_PREFIX + "addSpuAndSkuInfo";
        DataResponseDto<Map<String, Object>> dataResponseDto;
        MultiValueMap<String,SpuSkuInfoBo> reqMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        reqMap.add("spuSkuInfoBo",spuSkuInfoBo);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,SpuSkuInfoBo>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(reqMap);
        dataResponseDto = restTemplate.postForObject(url,httpEntity,DataResponseDto.class);
   }
```

This is my provider:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/addSpuAndSkuInfo")
    public DataResponseDto<Map<String, Object>> addSpuAndSkuInfo(SpuSkuInfoBo spuSkuInfoBo) {
        DataResponseDto<Map<String, Object>> responseDto;
        try {
            responseDto = spuSkuService.addSpuAndSkuInfo(spuSkuInfoBo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("addSpuAndSkuInfo", e);
            responseDto = new DataResponseDto<>();
            responseDto.setRspCd(PrdErrorCode.PRD_FAIL_CD);
            responseDto.setRspInf("");
            return responseDto;
        }
        return responseDto;
    }
```

In consumer I can got the Pojo 'SpuSkuInfoBo'
And When I debugger in provider, I just can not receive the request body 'SpuSkuInfoBo'

[image]

Comment: First of all, why is the consumer annotated?  I don't follow what you're trying to do there.  Second, if you're passing in an object over the wire (e.g., via an HTTP request), how are you serializing that object?

Comment: I want to send data(pojo) to provider in consumer

Comment: I get that.  Why are you annotating the consumer?  It looks like you're converting parts of your POJO into a map: `HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,SpuSkuInfoBo>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(reqMap);`  Unclear why you'd do that and also, it means the data you are trying to pass in to the backend does not match the signature of the backend method.  In short, you're doing much more than you need to.  Just make sure the POJO is serializable and, if your client and server share a common SDK, you are done - pass the POJO.

Comment: How is this spring cloud related and not just spring Framework?

Comment: Could you add : HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders() and you can a default content type ; then you replace with : 
HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,SpuSkuInfoBo>> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,SpuSkuInfoBo>>(reqMap,headers);

Comment: @sofend You mean PostMapping annotation? cause I use chrome send a request to consumer. And SpringBoot has default json convertor to serialize objects. And I change dataResponseDto = restTemplate.postForObject(url,httpEntity,DataResponseDto.class) To dataResponseDto = restTemplate.postForObject(url,spuSkuInfoBo,DataResponseDto.class) get the same result

Comment: @TinyOS ive try that and still get same result

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem by adding @RequstBody in provider function

`public DataResponseDto<Map<String, Object>> addSpuAndSkuInfo(@RequestBody SpuSkuInfoBo spuSkuInfoBo)`